# How to add value in a variable in every loop?

Tags: java, json, loops

I want to to add the first Json string that I parse to `int` and add then add it to the next Json string.

```
I/System.out: [{"checkdate":"Dec 5, 2016","checkno":"1231212","datepaid":"Dec 5, 2016","clientname":"sjkdfh","bank":"asj","amount":"123","status":"UNFINISHED"},{"checkdate":"Dec 5, 2016","checkno":"123","datepaid":"Dec 5, 2016","clientname":"asdjaksd","bank":"sandakjsn","amount":"123123","status":"UNFINISHED"}]
I/System.out: 123
I/System.out: 123123
```

I want to add 123 to 123123 here's my code

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray arr = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("message");
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

if (success) {
    System.out.println(arr);
    if (arr != null) {
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length();i++){
            listdata.add(arr.get(i).toString());
            String money = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("amount");
            int money1 = Integer.parseInt(money);

            System.out.println(money1);
        }

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to calculate the sum of the amounts?

Comment: yes sir. thats what i want 123 + 123123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<arr.length();i++){
    listdata.add(arr.get(i).toString());
    String money = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("amount");
    sum += Integer.parseInt(money);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```